# Why does Python let me define a variable in one scope, but use it in another?

Tags: python

I see that it's possible to define a variable inside a scope, but then refer to it outside that scope. For instance, the following code works:

```
if condition:
    x = 5
else:
    x = 10
print x
```

However, this strikes me as a bit weird. If you tried to do this in C, the variable X would not be scoped properly:

```
if(condition) { int x = 5; }
else { int x = 10; }
print x; // Doesn't work: x is unavailable!
```

The solution, in C anyway, is to declare X first, THEN figure out what do to with it:

```
int x;
if(condition) { x = 5; }
else { x = 10; }
print x; // Works!
```

So, in Python, my instinct is to write code like this:

```
x = None
if condition:
    x = 5
else:
    x = 10
print x
```

However, I realize Python doesn't require me to do this. Any suggestions? Is there a style guideline for this scenario?

Comment: Why do you ask questions but never accept answers?

Comment: As an aside: you should just relax about the whole scoping issue. Your first block of code is absolutely fine. The laws of logic will hold for at least the next version of Python :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Perhaps there's no definitive answer for this question? I appreciate the discussion.

Answer (score 17):

Blocks do not create a new scope in Python. Modules, classes, and functions do.

Also:

```
x = 10
if condition:
    x = 5
print x
```

or:

```
x = 5
if not condition:
    x = 10
print x
```

Comment: This is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: For the sake of completeness: also generator expressions, lambda expressions, and in Python 3 list comprehensions, create new scopes.

Comment: While it's possible not to pre-define the variable, is it advisable / good convention? Isn't it at least more descriptive to declare, before a business logic block, that we are now seeking value for this specific variable, `x`?

Comment: It can add clarity to set it to a default value and then use logic to change the value afterwards, but setting it to an unrelated value (such as `None` in the question) and then changing it unconditionally after reduces it slightly.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion:

Write Python, not C.

In Python we use blocks. An `if` is a block. A block doesn't necessarily mean a different scope in Python.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you might try this:

```
x = 10
if condiiton:
    x = 5
print x
```

As for why Python doesn't have the same scoping rules as C (and C++ and Java), the short answer is that they're different languages.  The long answer has to do with efficiency.  In C, these scoping rules are all handled at compile time, there's no runtime overhead.  In Python, it would have to store an inner scope in a new `dict`, and that would add overhead.  I'm sure there are other reasons, but this is a big practical one.

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating a new scope, so there's no scoping problem.

However, note that if you do something like:

```
if foo:
    x = 10
print x
```

You'll get a NameError raised if `foo` is False, so you might come across a case where you actually do want to define your variable outside of the conditional (or add an `else` to assign it `None`.)